# C#, xamarin, binding many objects

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding

So I've got a bunch of Frame objects that I'm adding to the display via code (the count of them is variable). And being true to MVVM, I need to bind the background color of each to something in the model. So the bind is simple:

```
Frame f1 = new Frame();
f1.SetBinding(Frame.BackgroundColorProperty, "BackColor1");
Frame f2 = new Frame();
f2.SetBinding(Frame.BackgroundColorProperty, "BackColor2");
```

And so on. That's just a quick example, the real thing is in a loop. And in the model:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Color BackColor1
{
    get
    {
        return Color.Black;
    }
}

Xamarin.Forms.Color BackColor2
{
    get
    {
        return Color.White;
    }
}
```

And so on. This works fine for a few objects, but what if there's 50? 100? I don't want to create a 100 BackColor properties in the class; that way lies madness. I've only being playing around in C# and xamarin for a few weeks now, so there's much I've still got to learn. What would be the best way to stay true to MVVM when you need to bind a large number of objects like this?

Comment: I think it would be very unlikely to have a use case where you need 100s or more distinct backing objects.  Generally when you see something anything like that you would have a collection of objects

Answer (score 0):

Are those colors gong to change once assigned? If so no need to stay in "true MVVM," which I assume you mean "using bindings." True MVVM does not require using bindings for everything, in fact if a property's value won't change once the object is instantiated, then using a binding is overkill. It is OK to use static values for properties and still be within "true MVVM." In fact static values for properties are better if the values are not going to be changed, or even not changed often, since bindings do have some performance overhead. So basically, every time you instantiate a new Frame, just set the BackgroundColor statically.

Comment: Yes, the background colors will be changing. All of these frames are instantiated in the xaml.cs, where I have pointers to them all. I can easily change the background colors from them in there, just wasn't sure if that was the best way to do it or if there was some kind of mass MVVM way to do it from the model.

Comment: You can bind the background color of multiple frames to one property, but if you do need a unique color for each frame, than i am afraid you will need a unique property to bind to for each frame's background color.

Comment: Yeah, they need to be unique. I'll just control the frames in the xaml.cs and pray the MVVM gods forgive me.